# Max Full width in container bootstrap 3

Tags: width, max

Hello I would like to have full-width div in container div.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- Start content -->

        <div class="normal_width"> Hello this is normal width in container </div>
        <div class="full_width"> This is Full width on container </div>

        <!-- End content -->
    </div> <!-- row -->
</div> <!-- container -->
</div> <!-- wrap -->
</body>
```

.normal_width is just like normal width. if I add background color, it should be "in container".

This is my question and problom (.full_width) If I add background color, It has to be width: 100% of whole layout (max full width). but I don't know how can I give css.

I am working on "full width video background" and "full width background color" on my layout which I wrote up there.

Any tips? I am working on it with Bootstrap 3.1

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In `<div class="row">` you should have elements with class "col-md-12" for full screen (http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/). Being responsive it will automatically resize. In later bootsrap they used class "span12" (http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html), which is no longer supported.

Comment: yes I need to add col-md-12. but I mean.. there is container which will make div arrange center. "normal_width" is ok. but I want full_width is max full width. like this site. http://minaolendemo.wordpress.com/ see articles and Portfolios. they are max full width. others are normal_width. I want to make like this.

the problem is that I have to keep "container" div as a wrap div.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with JavaScript and CSS:

**CSS:**

```
.full_width {
        left: 50%;
        position: relative;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
```

**JavaScript (requires jQuery):**

```
 function calculateFullWidth() {
        var calculatedWidth = $("body").width();
        $(".full_width").css({
            width: calculatedWidth
        })
    }
 calculateFullWidth();
 $(window).on("resize", calculateFullWidth);
```

you can remove the padding on the .full_width - Element if you want the Element to be 100 % Width

**Here is a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/b4y8UnOSmBy9YaQjrH7H?p=preview)**